# How can I find the domain of $ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log(1-t^{2})+t^{2}}{t}dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, improper-integrals

Let $$ h(x) =  \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log(1-t^{2})+t^{2}}{t}dt \ .$$
How can I find the domain of this function? I tried to integrate it, but it seems impossible; I also thought that it could be the domain of g(x): $$g(x) = \frac{\log(1-t^{2})+t^{2}}{t}dt$$ but on a second thought I realized that if some general function $f(x)$ has domain $D_{f}$ that doesn't implie that $f'(x)$ has this same domain (for example, if $f(x) = |x|$).

What do you suggest?
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $ h(x) $ exists, then $ h(-x) $ will also exist.

So, we can assume that $ x>0$.

Near $ 0^+$, we have

$$\ln(1-t^2)+t^2\sim -\frac{t^4}{2}$$
So,
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-t^2)+t^2}{t}=0$$
and
$$\int_0 f(t)dt \; converges$$

where $ f $ is the integrand function, which is defined at $ (-1,0)\cup (0,1)$.

but
$$\int^1f(t)dt \text{ is convergent}$$
because $ \int^1\ln(1-t)dt $ is known to be convergent.

The domain is then $$D=[-1,1]$$

Comment: I'm sorry, how did you conclude that h(-x) also exists?

Comment: @arpg By the substitution $ u=-t$.